# Where do ports get in the OSI model

Tags: networking, port, osi

I know that ports are part of the Transport layer.But when i ask an application to open a port how does it open a port and what is the port's part in the other layers ,and when the data is transferred to the other end of the communication how does it find the other port which is open in the other point?.

Comment: What does the defunct OSI model have to do with it?

Comment: And what does your title have to do with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ports which are public. For example Client A wants to communicate with Server.Now the server has some ports public say port 80.The Client A sends the traffic on port 80 of the server but if Client A keeps on sending its traffic on port 80 of Server then the other Clients cannot communicate with Server.So, after intial interaction Client A with Server on port 80 then Server tell Client A that our further communication should take place on this port eg port 6892.

Comment: another question,does the socket contains each sides ports?

Comment: Rubbish. All HTTP clients communicate with the server on port 80 if that is the listening oort. There is no second port for further communications. `netstat` on a busy server shows it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Ports are in the Transport layer, as you noted yourself. The remainder of your question doesn't make much sense. There is a *protocol,* which contains port numbers, and an *implementation,* which makes use of them. It's difficult to see what the mystery is.

Comment: he seems to be asking about the source port

Comment: @MikePennington It's anybody's guess, and it doesn't make any difference to the answer.